# fabric replace blocks in world creates ghost blocks

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

###### Context

I'm writing a fabric mod that needs to replace blocks in the world.

###### Code

Currently Im using `World#setBlockState(pos, state)`

```java
BlockPos pos = new BlockPos(x, y, z);
BlockState state = Blocks.STONE.getDefaultState();
world.setBlockState(pos, state);
```

###### Problem

This seems to work, but if I right-click the replaced blocks, they turn back into the block they were before

I also tried this `Block.replace(world.getBlockState(pos), state, world, pos)`, but this reproduces the same.

For now, the mod is only supposed to be used on client-side with `minecraft-1.17.1`.

###### Question

Is this because the client cannot modify the world in that way?

If not, what could be the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such as you mentionned, it's on the client-side. So, you can change everything, it will only be visual.

It replaced the block when right-click because the server send the real block present on the world (instead of visual one).

If you want to do something like that, it can be difficult. All client that are manually placing block on server are cheat, because they are making something that is not allowed in basic minecraft.

But, maybe there is possibilities :

1. Use [event](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:events) to change the block that will be placed, and instead of placing the default one and change it after, you can directly change it on the server.
2. Run a command to change the block such as `/setblock` ([wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/setblock))